# Extract dict value from list of dict in python

Tags: python

I have a list of dicts like this:

```
[{'name': 'John', 'age': 25}, {'name': 'Matt', 'age': 35} , {'name': 'Peter', 'age': 40}]
```

How can I get the name for those whose age is between 20-30 ?

Many thanks for your help.

Comment: You start with a `for` loop.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Something like this should do it:

```
list_of_dicts = [{'name': 'John', 'age': 25}, {'name': 'Matt', 'age': 35} , {'name': 'Peter', 'age': 40}]
names = [d['name'] for d in list_of_dicts if 20 <= d['age'] <= 30]
```

Answer (score 0):

You would use something like this:

```
dicta = {'name': 'John', 'age': 25}, {'name': 'Matt', 'age': 35} , {'name': 'Peter', 'age': 40}

for val in dicta:
  if 20 <= val['age'] <= 30:
    print(val['name'])
```

You seem to be new to Python so I suggest you look at some tutorials for example like [this one](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_dictionary.htm) on TutorialsPoint. Walks you through dictionaries.